# Is Login-AzureRmAccount an object or do I need to store it in one?

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a question about the Login-AzureRmAccount cmdlet and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.  When I run Login-AzureRmAccount and authenticate with my credentials, does a credential object get stored anywhere?  If I'm writing a script with lots of Azure cmdlets, do I need to keep those credentials around or store those somehow to pass into other cmdlets, or do I get some sort of authentication token which stays with me for a while?  I've done a little bit of research on this and I apologize if my google-fu was weak on this subject.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, now that you can use context persistence, this is less useful.  If you run  `Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave` then PowerShell will store this context container in '%AppData%\Roaming\Windows Azure PowerShell', so that you won't need to log in again the next time you open a powershell window.

Answer (score 1):

Login-AzureRmAccount returns a `AzureContextContainer` object.  You *can* store this and use it later with `Set-AzureRmContext`, or `Save-AzureRmContext` .  Mainly the object can be captured and used by scripts, and presents a display of hopefully relevant information to the shell window.

Note that, currently a new context is created for each PowerShell window, there are cmdlets that allow you to save (`Save-AzureRmContext`) and import (`Import-AzureRmContext`) a context, so that you could add such a command to your user profile and always start with the same context. .  This is slated to change over the summer, as a new feature will allow a set of contexts to automatically persist across PowerShell sessions.

Comment: This is true, and you can Export the container object to a file. This is helpful if you want to later Import the context/credentials to avoid having your script prompt you for your live credentials...

PS C:\> Save-AzureRmContext -Profile (Add-AzureRmAccount) -Path C:\test.json

then

PS C:\> Import-AzureRmContext -Path C:\test.json

Answer (score 0):

`Login-AzureRmAccount` does not have any objects that need to be kept around. Once you call it it sets an ambient context other calls will use. You can modify this context, for example to change which subscription and tenent you commands will communicate with by using the `Set-AzureRmContext` commandlet.

The only "context object" I have ever needed to use is the object returned from a `New-AzureStorageContext` which would be built up from a `Get-AzureStorageKey` call that uses the ambient context. That context object would be used with commandlets from the `Azure.Storage` module and would be passed in with the `-context` parameter.

Here is a script I use to create a new storage container that shows both the abient context and the storage container context in use

```
$resourceGroupName = "MyResourceGroup"
$storageAccountName ="examplestorageaccount"
$storageContainerName = "zips"
$resourceGroupLocation = "centralus"


#******************************************************************************
# Script body
# Execution begins here
#******************************************************************************
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# sign in
Write-Host "Logging in...";
$null = Login-AzureRmAccount;

# select subscription
$subscriptionId = ( Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title “Select an Azure Subscription …” -PassThru).SubscriptionId

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Register RPs
$resourceProviders = @("microsoft.storage");
if($resourceProviders.length) {
    Write-Host "Registering resource providers"
    foreach($resourceProvider in $resourceProviders) {
        $null = Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace $resourceProvider;
    }
}

#Create or check for existing resource group
$resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$resourceGroup)
{
    Write-Host "Creating resource group '$resourceGroupName' in location '$resourceGroupLocation'";
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $resourceGroupLocation
}
else{
    Write-Host "Using existing resource group '$resourceGroupName'";
}

#Create or check for existing storage account
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$storageAccount)
{
    Write-Host "Account not found, creating new storage account $storageAccountName";
    $storageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -Location $resourceGroupLocation -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SkuName Standard_LRS -Kind Storage
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Using existing storage account $storageAccountName'";
}

$storageAccountKey0 = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Value[0]
$storageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey0

#Create or check for existing storage container
$storageContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $storageContainerName -Context $storageAccountContext -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$storageContainer)
{
    Write-Host "Container not foind, creating new storage container $storageContainerName"
    $storageContainer = New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $storageContainerName -Permission Blob -Context $storageAccountContext
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Using existing storage container $storageContainerName'";
}

Write-Host "------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "New defaults for WriteToStorageAccount.ps1"
Write-Host '$storageAccountName =' "'$storageAccountName'"
Write-Host '$storageContainerName =' "'$storageContainerName'"
Write-Host '$key =' "'$storageAccountKey0'"
```